# Add delay for addClass

Tags: jquery, delay

By click I move an element outside of the browser window. After this animation I'd like to add a class to this element, but unfortunately the new class is already added as I click to the moving icon.

My Code:

```
$('#nav').click(function() {
$( "#wrapper" ).animate({ marginLeft: "-80%" }, "slow" );
$( "#nav_mob" ).show();
$( "#nav_mob" ).animate({ right: "-20%" }, "slow" );
$('.content').delay(2000).addClass("fixed");            
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: CSS Transition will fit you need. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$( "#nav_mob" ).animate({ right: "-20%" }, "slow" );
$('.content').delay(2000).addClass("fixed");
```

do:

```
$( "#nav_mob" ).animate({ right: "-20%" }, "slow", function(){
    $('.content').delay(2000).addClass("fixed");
});
```

This takes advantage of the callback built into `.animate()` where the arguments are:

- an object containing the properties to change
- the speed of the animation
- a function to call once the animation is complete

Answer (score 0):

`.delay()` doesn't work with `.addClass()` (it only works with the effects queue or a custom queue), but you can use the `setTimeout()` function instead:

```
$('#nav').click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").animate({
        marginLeft: "-80%"
    }, "slow");
    $("#nav_mob").show();
    $("#nav_mob").animate({
        right: "-20%"
    }, "slow");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.content').addClass("fixed");
    }, 2000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the addClass code in animate complete function

```
  $( "#nav_mob" ).animate({ right: "-20%" }, "slow",function(){
    $('.content').addClass("fixed");            
  });
```